# How do I change the email used when I edit a file on GitHub?

Tags: github

[GitHub](https://github.com/)'s web-based editor is great for making a quick change to a file.  But how can I set the email address used in my commit?  I have several email addresses associated with my account. It seems to use what GitHub thinks is the primary email address (the one GitHub uses to send me email), but I can't figure out how to change that either.

(Note: I know how to change my email address in a local repository using `git config`.  I'm only asking about GitHub's online editor.)

Answer (score 5):

Github is going to use the **first** address listed in your *Account Settings/Email Addresses*.

Right now the only way I know to change the primary email address that is used, it to delete the email addresses above the one you want to use, then add them back after the email address you want to use is at the top.